# How to retrieve a nodeValue from a specific tag content?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a variable $url contain an html page.What i want, is to get all the script tags nodeValue as some script tag might be in the head part or anywhere in the html.This is what I have done so far.

```
    $url = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace=FALSE;
    $els = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
        foreach($els as $d){
    echo $d->nodeValue;
          }
        echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: So what goes wrong? Do you get an error? And I think you need to run `htmlspecialchars` on the value before echoing.

Comment: Ya i got an error and am not getting the expected output..When i try with 'div' i get the output..i want to get the content between all the script tag which can be found in an html page.